# PHP/MySQL - ORDER by not working

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
if($_rate->getCode()=="matrixrate_matrixrate") {

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');


$query = 'select * from `extensa_econt_city_office` WHERE `delivery_type`="to_office" GROUP by `city_id`';

$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

?>
<center><b>Населено място:</b></center>
<select name="shipping_city" id="shipping-city-select" title="">
<option value="">Изберете град</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $row){
    $CityCode = $row['city_id'];
    $query1 = "select * from `extensa_econt_city` WHERE `city_id`='$CityCode' AND `type`!='с.' ORDER by office_id DESC";
    $results1 = $readConnection->fetchAll($query1);
    foreach($results1 as $row1){
    ?>          

<option value="<?PHP echo $row1['city_id']; ?>"><?PHP echo $row1['type']; ?> <?PHP echo $row1['name']; ?></option>

    <?php
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

For some reason the ordering with `ORDER by office_id DESC` is not working.
There is no change if I change `DESC` to `ASC` or even if I remove the `ORDER by` statement.

Do you have any suggestion why it is not ordering the rows properly ?

Comment: All I see right know is that you're missing the ` quotes around office_id. But I'm pretty sure it's not the solution. Can you give us an example of the result you are getting from the request ? (with the office_id value of each row)

Comment: @Eria what difference could that make? *"All I see right know is that you're missing the ` quotes around office_id"*

Comment: When you try the SQL statement form the MySQL command line does it work as you expect? You're not doing any error checking, which is worrisome.

Comment: Your query inside the `foreach loop` that's make the problem in `ASC or DESC`

Comment: So how can i resolve that problem @Saty ?

Comment: a) make a JOIN to reduce both queries to one; b) store the results in an array and sort it before you print it.

Comment: Well, what I see, is in fact spaghetti code. I advise you not to mix client code and server PHP code. You'd better familiarize yourself with PHP template engines and AJAX. That will allow you to separate view from some business logic. And my final advice to you (at the time when you have some "baby" code), is not to use MySQL, but to switch to Postgres (or Oracle, or MS SQL).

Comment: if you change the $query in line 8 where there is `delivery_type="to_office"` to `delivery_type=\'to_office\' `, would it work?

Comment: And besides, it seems like you have not heard about SQL statements preparation. In PHP (as well as in all other popular languages), you have a lot of techniques to prepare statements and prevent major security vulnarabilities.

Comment: Why r u not using a join query...

Comment: And finally we see that your are using `GROUP BY` statement without aggregation functions (like `MAX`, `SUM` etc.). It is not that terrible, but it does not obey SQL standard. So at some moment when you decide to migrate to other RDBMS (frantically trying to forget MySQL as a nigthmare), it will be a hard nut to crack.

Comment: Ups:)  My final advice to you, is to get acquainted with ORM. It is not that good that you scatter around  a lot of SQL statements. The better way is to isolate all database management in a single "layer".

Comment: And i suggest to use inner join qiery than use group by city id and order by office...

Answer (score -2):

You Missing ``(quotes) around office_id
if you still find that query is not working then print whole query using echo statement..
copy that query and paste in php-myadmin and check which sql exception you getting..

Comment: The quotes are optional, they are only needed when a column has the name of a reserverd keyword.

Answer (score -2):

hi maybe you can check your sintaxis your code maybe have a little error
for this i suggest that you run your query on phpmyadmin and check if the result is correct , then is correct the result you have a debug on your code php
this a little example for you

```
<?php
$link=Conect(); 
$query="SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY client_name ASC";
$result=mysql_query($query,$link) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

?>
<table border="0">
   <tr COLSPAN=2 BGCOLOR="#6D8FFF">
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>NAME</td>
      <td>PHONE</td>
   </tr>
 <?php     
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
      echo "<tr>".
           "<td>".$row["id"]."</td>".
           "<td>".$row["client_name"]."</td>".
           "<td>".$row["phone"]."</td>".
           "</tr>";
 } /

}
else
{
     echo "don't exist clients for list";
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
</table>
```

good luck and try

Comment: Please don't advertise the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, especially when the OP already used a more modern framework